# Dictionary<TKey, TValue> override Indexer and FindEntry

Tags: c#, dictionary, mono

In order to optimize my code, I'm trying to create my own `Indexer` and my own version of the `FindEntry` function - so that I can do something like the following within a `Dictionary`-like class:

```
object IDictionary.this[int key] {
    get {
        int num = this.FindEntry(key);
        if (num >= 0) {
            return this.entries[num].value;                 
        }

        return null;
    }

    set {
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.VerifyValueType(value);
        this [key] = (TValue)((object)value);
    }
}

private int FindEntry (int key) {
    if (this.buckets != null) {
        int num = key & 2147483647;
        for (int i = this.buckets[num % this.buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = this.entries[i].next) {
            if (this.entries[i].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[i].key, key)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is useful because my dictionary's key is a struct - but sometimes I have the hashcode rather than the key.

I'm looking for a solution *other than* rewriting `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` from `System` - but I suspect that may be the only method, because the variable `entries` within it is private.

Below is a basic example of my code, to help show what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
struct SuperKey : IEquatable<SuperKey> {
    public int Id;
    public int Environment;

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other) {
        return other is SuperKey ? Equals((SuperKey)other) : false;
    }

    public bool Equals(SuperKey other) {
        return this.Id == other.Id && this.Environment == other.Environment;
    }
}
```

and

```
class Example {
    Dictionary<SuperKey, Player> players;

    void MyFunction() {
        SuperKey sk = new SuperKey(36, 1);
        Player p1 = new Player();

        players.Add(sk, p1);
    }

    void ReceiveEventForPlayer(int id, PlayerEventName name) {
        ReceiveEventForPlayer(id, 0, name);
    }

    void ReceiveEventForPlayer(int id, int environment, PlayerEventName name) {
        Player p = players[new SuperKey(id, 1)];
    }

}
```

In the `ReceiveEventForPlayer` method just above this, please note the line:

> `Player p = players[new SuperKey(id, 1)];`

I would much prefer to be able to use:

> `Player p = players[id];`

But this doesn't work... It would actually be *most* ideal to be able to use *either* syntax.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Is this class derived from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`? What do you mean about having the hashcode but not having the key? You'll need to clarify your question before we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I have a struct : SuperKey { public int id; public int environment; }

In this struct I override the gethashcode function to return this.id.

So it's will be useful in some case to use a int instead of create a struct to find a element in my dictionary. ( for example, if I run my application in a certain mode 'environment' is always equals to 0 )

Actually I don't understand how I can override FindEntry, I think  if I create a class that derived from Dictionary<TKey, TValue> I cannot access to the private variable Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.entries.

I hope It's more easy to understand.

Comment: You should edit all of this into your question rather than as comments. Frankly a mutable struct with public fields is a bad idea anyway IMO, but that's a different matter. Have you also overridden `Equals`? Are you implementing `IEquatable<SuperKey>`? To be honest, it sounds like you just want a dictionary with an `int` key instead of `SuperKey` at all.

Comment: Yes. Is just in some case my application run on different database and sometime it's run an only one database. And I need an element (environment) to make a difference with two User with the same Id but different value ( cause there is not in the same database ).

Comment: In that case you *can't* just use the `id` to find an entry, can you? You need the full key. Again, I think you're confused about what you really need, to be honest.

Comment: In Debug, environment can be equals to 0, 1, 2, 3 etc ... because a User ( for example ) is from a database, and the user id = 1 in the database 1 is not the same that the user id = 1 in the database 2.

In Release, environment is always equals to 0 because I use only one database. So in my event ( that come from a socket for example ), I'm not sending a useless int ( the environment ) cause it always equals to 0.

But I think I will use more some #if DEBUG ...

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest that you don't end up with different code in your debug environment to your production environment. Surely the point of a debug environment is to be able to try your code before you deploy it to production. That's not much use if you're testing different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a lot of assumptions about the implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that might not be valid. For example:

- You're assuming that collisions are resolved by open addressing. They could just as easily be addressed by re-hashing or by chaining.
- You're assuming that the bucket location is computed by dividing the returned hash code by the number of buckets. There are other possibilities.
- Even if those two assumptions prove correct, you're assuming that the implementation won't change in the future and invalidate your previous assumptions.

You're also making the assumption that you can access the base class's internal data structures, which is not possible. As far as I know, there's no `buckets` array in the `Dictionary` class's protected interface.

From what you posted, it seems that the only execution time you'd save, if your assumptions were correct, would be the time spent computing the hash code for each item. That's easily solved by computing the item's hash code when you create it (i.e. in the constructor), and caching it. Your `GetHashCode` method, then, is just `return this.cachedHashCode;`

That assumes, of course, that the items you're placing in the dictionary are immutable. Or, at minimum, any fields that are used to determine equality are immutable.

And, finally, are you certain that the `Dictionary` is the limiting factor in your program's performance? If not, perhaps your optimization efforts would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: It's not really to improve performance. Is just if it will be easy to override findentry and access to entries and buckets... it's would be more logic in my case to not create a superkey object if I decide to run my application in the mode 'unique database'.

Answer (score 0):

Jim and Jon is correct and I think the solution to your problem is simple:

Just change to `GetHashCode` to make a concatenation of db number, "-", and user number and then call the base GetHashCode on that string.

In this way you don't have to change the implementation in production and debug.